# Delete hasMany items with files using Eloquent

Tags: laravel

I have `Ad`, which hasMany `AdPhoto`

```
// Ad model
public function ad_photos() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\AdPhoto')->orderBy('position', 'desc');
}
// AdPhoto model
public static function boot() {
  parent::boot();
  AdPhoto::deleting(function($photo) {      
    \File::delete(public_path('photos').'/'.$photo['filename']);    
  }
}
```

It works on deleting AdPhoto directly (deletes db record and file):

```
\App\AdPhoto::find($id)->delete();
```

It doesn't work on deleting Ad (doesn't delete files, only db records):

```
\App\Ad::find($id)->ad_photos()->delete();
```

How to make it work?

(Laravel 5.4)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method in the `AdPhoto` model and use it instead of using event:

```
AdPhoto::deletePhotos($adId);
```

Method example:

```
public static function deletePhotos($adId)
{
    $photos = this->where('ad_id', $adId)->get();
    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
        \File::delete(public_path('photos').'/'.$photo['filename']);
    }
    return $this->destroy($photos->pluck('id')->toArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try create [Event Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events) for listening on delete event.

So your `AdPhoto` observer would have this function to handle delete.

```
public function deleting(\App\AdPhoto $photo)
{
    // remove from storage here
    \File::delete(public_path('photos').'/'.$photo->filename); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this:

```
foreach($ad->ad_photos()->get() as $photo) {
    $photo->delete();
}
```